# Clip polygon to multiple polygons

Tags: vector, arcgis-pro, clip

I have nine vector land use .shp and I had to make a cropland shapefile, but I thought of giving my study region polygon an attribute to be cropland, instead of digitizing it.

I forgot what function I had to use to overlay my landuse vectors file over this cropland vector file and to clip it in order to have empty spots (donuts) where the landuse files cover the cropland. Basically I want my study area to have empty spots within in the spots where other landuse vectors are over it.

I use ArcGIS Pro

Comment: You haven't mentioned what GIS package you are using, making it very difficult to provide command references. Please [Edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the erase command. It looks like what you want.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Thank you so much for your help